# how to get the content image or video of the post from this twitter json

Tags: java, android, json, twitter-oauth

I get User this:

```
//Get Tweets
$statuses = $connection->get("statuses/user_timeline", ["screen_name" => "michaeljackson","count" => 20, "exclude_replies" => true]);
```

and I have this json, where could I know if the post has an Image or not and what is the URL of the image of the post

```
 http://emadzedan80-001-site1.gtempurl.com/
```

I'm using Android studio using Java, I'm just in the beginning I just want to know where are each value I need then I will start coding

Comment: Try to learn from this : [android-tutorial-json-parsing-using-retrofit-part-1](http://www.pratikbutani.com/2016/05/android-tutorial-json-parsing-using-retrofit-part-1/)

Comment: I do not need parsing tutorial I need someone experienced with Twitter API to show me how to get Image of the post from the JSON, I mean which field is the image of the post